# HTML/CSS: How to get the id of sub menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

If I have a index.html file with code:

```html
<li><a href="#">QA</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="1.html">current-status</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2.html">update status</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I need to get an id of current-status and update-status when I click on this menu, which is the sub-menu of QA.

Comment: please check [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please check answer of Dhara Parmar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".main").click(function(){
   $(this).find("li").each(function() {
     console.log($(this).attr('id'))
   })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="main"><a href="#">QA</a>
   <ul>
     <li id="current_status"><a href="1.html">current-status</a>
     </li>
     <li id="update_status"><a href="2.html">update status</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I think your answer is best as per described on question

Answer (score 1):

try this, it is very easy with jQuery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
 
<li class="mainli">QA
   <ul>
 <li id="current">current</li>
 <li id="update">update</li>
   </ul>
</li>
 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("li.mainli ul li").click(function(){//this line you call to the list element inside the mainli class then get the ul element and after that it gets li element 
   var theclickedId = $(this).attr("id");//in this line it takes the id value of the each item click by there user
   alert(theclickedId);
  });
 });
</script>
</html>
```

for your requested second part of the question , mentioned in the comment 
do it like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 

  <li class="mainli">PUBLIC 
     <ul> 
     <li id="PUBLIC_current">current</li> 
     <li id="PUBLIC_update">update</li> 
     </ul> 
  </li> 
  <li class="mainli">DEV 
   <ul> 
   <li id="DEV_current1">current</li> 
   <li id="DEV_update1">update</li> 
   </ul> 
  </li>
 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("li.mainli ul li").click(function(){
   
   var getmainId = $(this).attr("id")
   alert(getmainId);

  });
 });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: How would I know that I have clicked on QA,current or QA,update.??

Comment: in the same way if I have <li class="mainli">PUBLIC
   <ul>
 <li id="current">current</li>
 <li id="update">update</li>
   </ul>
</li>
one more then how can i distinguis the that I clicked on QA current or PUBLIC current

Comment: you mean you want to use same class names. to do that use different `id` names. I added the answer for your second part.

Comment: no, I want a different id name so that ,I can distinguish that current is a part of QA or Update is a part of QA,  In the similar manner I can have PUBLIC with again current and update,In you code you are getting the same ID name so I cannot distinguish them weather it is a part of QA or PUBLIC.

Comment: try above code, it gives different id names for each element